# How to change [esc] behavior only in normal mode?

Tags: split, escape

I'm hoping I phrased the question correctly as I'm not too sure how to ask my question.

When I work in vim I use multiple "splits" (eg. `:vsp`, `:sp`). To navigate through the splits I have it set up so that the `tab` key cycles through them:

```
nmap <Tab> <C-w>w 
nmap <S-Tab> <C-w>W
```

When in normal mode or when I exit a mode and return to `normal mode` (by using `esc`), I'd like to change the functionality of the `esc` key so that it works like the `tab` key (it begins to cycle the focus through the open tabs). Then when I enter another mode, the functionality of `esc` should switch back to the expected behavior, and allow me to exit that mode, without switching tabs.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: If I may give my unsolicited advice: Don't remap `esc` to do that. I you want to avoid having to debug issues and inconsistent behavior you should only create mapping which extends Vim built-in behavior, not mappings which change the default behavior. It might look like a good idea at first you will realize that remapping `esc` like you want has edge cases or will block you in the future in other situation. If you really want to use the `esc` key an alternative would be to use `<Leader><Esc>` instead. Also always use non recursive map commands (`nnoremap`) unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I miss the point, but you should have your answer already (replace `<tab>` with `<esc>`):

```
nmap <Esc> <C-w>w
```

`n` in `nmap` means `normal`, thus you map your key only for a normal mode.